# How to sort an array in tcl?

Tags: tcl, sorting

I have an array of this type :

```
cat1 A B C 12
cat1 E F G 10
cat2 C F G 4
cat2 H F S 12
cat3 F G M -12
...
```

I don't know how many categries I have for input.

I want to have in the output one file by category, sorted with the last column

```
cat1 E F G 10
cat1 A B C 12
```

for the first file

```
cat2 C F G 4
cat2 H F S 12
```

for the second file, etc ....

I triied this :

i put every line in a $list {{cat1 A B C 12} {cat1 E F G 10} .....}

After, I sort it :

set list [lsort -index 4 -real $list]

```
foreach element $list {
            regexp {.*} [lindex [split $element " "] 0] start
            set table_cat($start) "$element"
    }
```

After, i write the files :

```
    foreach element [array names table_cat] {
            set thefile [open "cat_$element.txt" "w"]
            puts $thefile "$table_cat($element)"
    }
```

But I have only 1 line in the result line !

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `regexp` is about, since you could have written simply,

```
set start [lindex [split $element " "] 0]
```

but maybe there's more to it and you simplified your example.

In any case, the reason you're only seeing one result per file is that you're overwriting `table_cat($start)` each time. What you probably mean to do is more like

```
lappend table_cat($start) "$element"
```

(By the way, `lappend` will create a list if it doesn't exist—so no need to "initialize".)

And then, you want to iterate like this:

```
foreach cat [array names table_cat] {
    foreach line $table_cat($cat) {
        // write $line to the file for $cat
    }
}
```

---

I have to say though, your naming is a bit weird. I would have written it like this, but to each his/her own:

```
foreach line $lines {
    set category [lindex [split $line " "] 0]
    lappend lines_by_category($category) $line
}

foreach category [array names lines_by_category] {
    set file [open "cat_$category.txt" "w"]
    foreach line $lines_by_category($category) {
        puts $file $line
    }
}
```